# string array to anagram string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, arraylist

```
   public static List<ArrayList> areAnagrams(string[] input)
    {
        List<ArrayList> anagramList = new List<ArrayList>();
        List<string> str = input.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            input[i] = input[i].ToLower();
            input[i] = input[i].Replace(" ", "");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.Add(input[i]);

            char[] string1 = input[i].ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(string1);               

            for (int j = i + 1; j < input.Length; j++)
            {
                char[] string2 = input[j].ToCharArray();
                Array.Sort(string2);

                if (string1.Length == string2.Length)
                {
                    bool isAnagram = true;

                    for (int k = 0; k < string1.Length; k++)
                    {
                        if (string1[k] != string2[k])
                        {
                            isAnagram = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isAnagram)
                    {
                        list.Add(input[j]);
                        //input[i].Remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            anagramList.Add(list);
        }

        return anagramList;
    }
```

`string[] str = new string[] { "pear", "dirty room", "amleth", "reap", "tinsel", "hamlet", "dormitory", "listen", "silent" }`

result should be:

`[ {"pear","reap"}, {"dirty room","dormitory"}, {"amleth","hamlet"}, {"tinsel","listen","silent"} ]`

problem is im not able to remove the words which already are inserted in the list

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer you expect, but just to show a different way

```
string[] input = new string[] { "pear", "dirty room", "amleth", "reap", "tinsel", "hamlet", "dormitory", "listen", "silent" };

var anagramList = input
       .Select(s => new { org = s, sorted = String.Join("", s.Where(c => c != ' ').OrderBy(c => c)) })
       .GroupBy(x => x.sorted)
       .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.org).ToList())
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "instant removing" just create `List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();`

Then add items to it, which you want to remove and after you are done, just create simple for-cycle:

```
foreach (string item in toRemove){
  input.delete(item);
}
```

(I am using Java most of time, so maybe this syntax is not 100% correct, but it is about the "how to do it")